# The difference between protocols for transferring data between Python API client and the DolphinDB server?

Tags: python, pickle, dolphindb, apache-arrow

I have a script with a `delete` statement, which always returned a DataFrame. Today I wrote a similar script, but I found that as long as the `delete` statement was included, an exception `IO Error Type 1` was thrown. Then I changed the protocol option to *PROTOCOL_DDB* according to [DolphinDB Python API documentation](https://github.com/dolphindb/api_python3), and it worked fine.

Having read the user guide, I have the following questions about the *protocols PROTOCOL_DDB*, *PROTOCOL_PICKLE*, and *PROTOCOL_ARROW*.

1. What are the specific differences in the usage scenarios of these three protocols?
2. Why is *PROTOCOL_PICKLE* used by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*PROTOCOL_DDB*, *PROTOCOL_PICKLE*, and *PROTOCOL_ARROW* are all protocols for serialization of objects in communication between DDB Python Api client and the server.

1. *PROTOCOL_ARROW* is the protocol from Apache Arrow. For more information, see [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/). Using this procotol, you only need to serialize data once when retrieving data from the database. There is no extra effort for further serialization and deserialization.
2. *PROTOCOL_DDB* is the most common protocol used for serialization/deserialization when transferring data. In addition to the Python API, other APIs, like JAVA API, C++ API, also use PROTOCOL_DDB.
3. *PROTOCOL_PICKLE* is based on Python's pickle protocol. For more
   information, see [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Some modifications have been made based on
   the 4.0 version of Pickle to fit DolphinDB.

Differences:

- In terms of conversion of data types: *PROTOCOL_PICKLE* and
  *PROTOCOL_DDB* have their own advantages and disadvantages for certain
  types.
- In terms of usage scenarios: *PROTOCOL_ARROW* is most suitable for scenarios where the arrow format is used as an intermediate format throughout the whole process (from data import to data consumption). If `pandas.DataFrame` is used a lot, then *PROTOCOL_PICKLE* and *PROTOCOL_DDB* are more suitable, For other general data types, *PROTOCOL_PICKLE* is relatively faster, which is why it is used by default.